# mongodb memory release

Tags: mongodb, memory-leaks

I am new to mongodb and doing some testing with it (1 master + 1 slave).
We inserted 2 million documents in couple of collections (Ubuntu, with 6G RAM, Quad core) and mongodb's memory increased from 40m to 4G (we are ok with it). Now we deleted all data and we were expecting memory (RSS) to go down back to 40m. Is it normal? Does mongodb takes time to flush mem (based on some scheduling)?

Just a fyi : performance (from frontend GUI ) was really good and improved a lot with adding indexes.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. MongoDB works with memory-mapped files.
2. MongoDB does not, unprompted, shrink the size of its files when records are deleted; it simply marks the space inside the files as free, to be reused.
3. You can force Mongo to reclaim space by rebuilding the database.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space

Comment: ran repairDatabase  31023 mongodb   20   0 88.7g 914m 633m S    0 16.0  99:16.53 mongod  still ~1G.

Comment: Is it RAM or actual disk usage that is at 1G?

Comment: it's RAM (RSS), disk space is much higher (which is ok for now), but memory is a concern.

Comment: To clarify, I mean size of the Mongo data files, not total disk usage.

Comment: As discussed in the documentation [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage#CheckingServerMemoryUsage-UnixUtilities) and [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/server-status/#memory-status) resident memory size will tend towards total RAM if MongoDB is the only process running.  This is not normally a problem as the OS will free memory as needed.  If this value exceeds system memory and you have a significant amount of data on disk that is not in RAM you may have exceeded the capacity of your system